# -bash: No such file or directory when trying to run a .cc file in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to run a file called driver.cc, which is a C file.  This C file calls a `sort.h` file.  I am in the correct folder when I type the following:

```
./driver random 20000 less
```

and I get the following error:

```
-bash ./driver no such file or directory.
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's C++, not C. Both C++ and C are compiled programming languages. You need a compiler (typically *gcc*) to generate executable binary code from C source code.

This is completely unlike scripts that have an *interpreter* that executes source code line by line (which is several orders of magnitude slower; something in the order of 1000 or 10000 times).

To compile a simple C++ program consisting of only a single source file, use

```
g++ -o driver driver.cc
```

In your simple case, you can even invoke `make` without creating a *Makefile*:

```
make driver
```

Now you can execute the newly created `driver` executable.

Caveat: You need build tools installed:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```